# Sematic release failing in gitlab ci for large number of commits

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, semantic-release

i am using semantic release with gitlab. I have added a job in ci for running semantic release which seems to run normally for normal number of commits but when i ran it on a branch with around 1500 commits it failed

Analyze commits run and then it fails with exit code 1

```
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Am using this command in ci
`semantic-release --debug`

It seems to be running fine when in run from my local
`semantic-release --no-ci`

Anyone has any idea what could be the issue and how i can solve it.

Is there any way to reduce the amounts of logs shown by semantic release plugins.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to reduce the number of commits. If you can afford to skip a version (probably since you are using semantic release), then figure out what would be the probable highest impacting release (breaking, feat, fix) and then manually tag the commit *before* that one with the next version. That way, semantic-release will only go back to the most recent tag and process considerably few messages.

```
$ export MOST_RECENT_SIGNIFICANT_TAG=f31b761673e1
$ export COMMIT_BEFORE_THAT=$(git rev-parse $MOST_RECENT_SIGNIFICANT_TAG^)
$ export LAST_KNOWN_VERSION="v1.2.2"
$ export NEXT_VERSION="v1.2.3" # Or whatever you manually decide
$ git tag $NEXT_VERSION $COMMIT_BEFORE_TAG
$ git push origin $NEXT_VERSION
```

Once you do that, then semantic-release won't go as far back and should pick up the next version and do the proper release.